# arcpy.da.UpdateCursor where clause persists

Tags: arcpy

I have some unexpected behaviour in an `UpdateCursor`. I'm iterating over quite a large dataset, and I've found that Python freaks out less if I break up the iteration into chunks:

```
env.workspace = r"ROADS.gdb"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("JUNCTIONS", "jn_layer")

for i in range(-70000, 1500000, 10000):
    strFilter = "UFI >= " + str(i) + " AND UFI < " + str(i+10000)
    print strFilter

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("jn_layer", ["OID@","UFI"], strFilter) as upCursor:
        for rowInt in upCursor:
            # do stuff
```

I would expect this to create a new cursor for each iteration with different filters, as per the `print` line:

```
UFI >= -70000 AND UFI < -60000
UFI >= -60000 AND UFI < -50000
UFI >= -50000 AND UFI < -40000
...etc
```

The problem is the first iteration works as expected, but each subsequent iteration of `i` returns no rows - it spits out each subsequent filter value but does nothing inside the `with` loop. Once it finishes, if I change the initial value:

```
for i in range(-60000, 1500000, 10000):
```

then it processes the first 10000 values (which were ignored before), but again the rest of the iterations of the `with` loop return no values. It feels like it's keeping the first filter on `jn_layer` and trying to apply the second filter to that filtered set, which of course returns no rows since there's no overlap between the ranges.

Is this the expected behaviour? I would have thought creating a cursor on a layer would only filter the layer for as long as the cursor exists, and the `with` keyword should be destroying the cursor before the filter changes...? Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Guessing at a possible solution: Perhaps `del upCursor` at the end of your for loop, to "reset" the cursor?

Comment: it looks like a feature layer is being passed to the updateCursor - it's possible to apply a clause to that layer, which could either be a potential solution, or perhaps there is a clause applied to it already?

Comment: Works as expected on my PC. I wouldn't use filter as variable though..

Comment: @Erica - as I read the docs, the `with` keyword takes care of deleting the `upCursor` as soon as it finishes the `for` loop...?
@fluidmotion - sorry, added the relevant lines. It is a feature layer, but there is no filter applied when it's created from the dataset.

Comment: @FelixIP - hah. Edited it from `strFilter` (in my code) to `filter` in case someone got all hatey on my wossname notation. Fail. :)

Comment: #do stuff looks interesting. You cannot change OID and UFI used as definition query. What are you actually updating please, unless it is top secret

Comment: Derp. Thank you @FelixIP for pointing me in the right direction. (insert comments about minimal working examples at your leisure. :) ) I had a call to `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("jn_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "...")` within the loop, and I'm guessing when I create the second `UpdateCursor` it's filtering on the selection, not the layer itself. Added `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("jn_layer", "CLEAR_SELECTION")` before the `UpdateCursor` and everything's happy. If you want to make an answer along those lines (clearing selections etc) I'll give you some happy points.

Comment: @FelixIP - That comment about not changing the fields you use in the filter is also interesting - do you have a link for that?

Comment: Yes when working with layers, cursors deal with selection if any. I am ok with no credits, you've figured it yourself. One cannot edit OID, because this is internal database thing. I didn't mean UFI, but it seemed too risky thing to do for variable in def.query. happy pythoninh

Comment: @Juffy The `with` keyword _should_ do cleanup (and apparently did, as your problem was elsewhere); I've occasionally had ArcPy not behave quite as expected, though, so thought it was worth suggesting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @FelixIP for steering me in the right direction.

Inside the loop (where I had `#do stuff`) I was making a selection on `"jn_layer"`:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("jn_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "...")
```

When the loop exits and the new cursor is created, that selection is still active and the cursor searches the **selection**, not the whole layer. Explicitly clearing the selection ahead of the cursor:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("jn_layer", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("jn_layer", ["OID@","UFI"], strFilter) as upCursor:
    [...]
```

resolved the issue.